# how to render <br /> to a new line in django template?

Tags: django, templates

I am trying to render a message in a template using django.
I used this code:

```
message = "hello <br /> how are you? " 
t = loader.get_template(template_html)
context = {"message":message}
return t.render(context)
```

The problem is that:

```
 I get hello <br /> how are you?
```

in the template instead of a new line, 
how can I fix this?

Comment: try safe template tag in your template. {{  message|safe }}

Comment: Also, can you move to `message = "hello \n how are you? " 
` and use [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) on template: `{{message | linebreaksbr}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either apply the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter in the template or mark `message` [as safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) in the view:

```
# template
{{ message|safe }}
```

or

```
# view
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
context = {"message": mark_safe(message)}
```

This will then render your message as html.